# Android: can't use fragment in a dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, fragment, dialogfragment

I have a quite complex situation, I'll try to explain:

I have three classes:

```
FleetListFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
FragmentFleetListMap extends FleetListFragment
FragmentFleetListReports extends FleetListFragment
```

now, this app is made of a drawer activity, which of course uses fragments; `FragmentFleetListMap` is used as a child fragment in one of the "main" fragments of the activity.

I want to use `FragmentFleetListReports` inside a custom dialog (`FleetSelectDialog`, which also contains other things) which is shown by one of the main fragments.

I tried this:

```
public class FleetSelectDialog extends Dialog{
    public FleetSelectDialog(Context context, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(context);
            this.context = context;
            this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
        }

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fleet_select_dialog, null);

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.list_select_frame, new FragmentFleetListReports(this)).commit();
    }
```

with fragmentManager passed from the main fragment: `new FleetSelectDialog(context, getFragmentManager());`

this gives this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0e0086 (com.Tierra:id/list_select_frame) for fragment FragmentFleetListReports
```

The other thing I tried is changing the dialog to be a `DialogFragment` but:

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.list_select_frame, new FragmentFleetListReports(this)).commit();
```

does not compile giving the error: `cannot resolve method: add(int, myPackage.FragmentFleetListReports)`
just like if `FragmentFleetListReports` is not extending Fragment

dialog layout looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fleet_select_dialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_select_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footerview"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

<!--other views-->

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I think I am missing something (especially on how `DialogFragment` works...) but I can't figure out how to solve this. Moving the other views to the fragment is not an option and neither is not using the fragment

if anyone can give any help, it would be great, thanks

Comment: Why not using `DialogFragment` instead of `Dialog` ?

Comment: As stated in the question, I tried but it doesn't compile, maybe I don't completely understand how a DialogFragment works

Comment: I think I figure out why I can't use a `DialogFragment`, it looks like the fragment class to be used in a `DialogFragment` must extends `DialogFragment`, I can't do that, I already have the fragment class (extending `Fragment`) and changing that is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using a `DialogFragment` containing a `FrameLayout` and adding my fragment to this frame. I think it's not the best way to do this, but it's working at least

DialogFragment:

public FleetSelectDialog() {

```
}
public static FleetSelectDialog newInstance() {
    FleetSelectDialog dialogFragment = new FleetSelectDialog();
    return dialogFragment;
}
```

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    fragmentFleetList = new FragmentFleetListReports();

    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.list_select_frame, fragmentFleetList).commit();
```

}

calling it this way:

```
fleetSelectDialog = FleetSelectDialog.newInstance();
                fleetSelectDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "");
```